# Getting the label of an OptionSetValue through SOAP Service in CRM 2011

Tags: silverlight, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a Silverlight application that needs to get the label of an OptionSetValue attribute from the Activity entity. The attribute logical name is **activitytypecode**, and I have the following extension method to retrieve an attribute metadata:

```
    public static void RetrieveAttribute(this IOrganizationService service,
        string entityLogicalName, string entityAttributeName,
        Action<OrganizationResponse> callback)
    {            
        var retrieveAttributeRequest = new OrganizationRequest()
        {
            RequestName = "RetrieveAttribute",
        };

        retrieveAttributeRequest["EntityLogicalName"] = entityLogicalName;
        retrieveAttributeRequest["RetrieveAsIfPublished "] = false;
        retrieveAttributeRequest["LogicalName"] = entityAttributeName;

        service.BeginExecute(retrieveAttributeRequest,
            result =>
            {
                if (result.IsCompleted)
                {
                    var response = service.EndExecute(result);

                    callback(response);
                }
            }, null);
    }
```

And I use it as follows on my SoapCtx that has already been initialized:

```
SoapCtx.RetrieveAttribute("activitypointer", "activitytypecode",
    orgResponse =>
    {
        if (orgResponse != null)
        {
            // examine orgResponse
        }
    });
```

I am able to debug the procedure but it fails on the line **var response = service.EndExecute(result);** in my extension method. I get the following Exception message:

> The remote server returned an error: NotFound.

Here's the StackTrace if you will find it useful:

```
{System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass5.<EndGetResponse>b__4(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginOnUI>b__1(Object sendState)
```

I appreciate any help or guidance, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the anonymous method the following worked for me. **Please note MetadataId**

```
    private void StartGetAttributeMetadata()
    {
        OrganizationRequest request = new OrganizationRequest() { RequestName = "RetrieveAttribute" };
        request["EntityLogicalName"] = "activitypointer";
        request["LogicalName"] = "activitytypecode";
        request["MetadataId"] = Guid.Empty;
        request["RetrieveAsIfPublished"] = true;

        IOrganizationService service = SOAPServerUtility.GetSoapService();
        service.BeginExecute(request, new AsyncCallback(EndGetAttributeMetadata), service);
    }

    private void EndGetAttributeMetadata(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        OrganizationResponse response = ((IOrganizationService)result.AsyncState).EndExecute(result);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, doing it this way works for me. I didn't try it this way because I thought it would be irrelevant since they both do the same thing except in different ways. It stinks that I can't use anonymous methods for this, and I don't know why the SOAP context goes haywire when it is done this way. I now don't have a choice but to write a bunch of separate event handlers for every request which I hate doing because it makes reading your code harder. Again, thanks a lot, this was driving me crazy for hours.